# How to create an operator in PostgreSQL for the hstore type with an int4range value

Tags: postgresql, operators, postgresql-9.2, database-indexes, hstore

I have a table with an HSTORE column 'ext', where the value is an int4range. An example:

```
"p1"=>"[10, 18]", "p2"=>"[24, 32]", "p3"=>"[29, 32]", "p4"=>"[18, 19]"
```

However, when I try to create an expression index on this, I get an error:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_test3_p1
ON test3
USING gist
(((ext -> 'p1'::text)::int4range));
```

> ERROR: data type text has no default operator class for access method
>   "gist" SQL state: 42704 Hint: You must specify an operator class for
>   the index or define a default operator class for the data type.

How do I create the operator for this?

**NOTE**

Each record may have its own unique set of keys. Each key represents an attribute, and the values the value range. So not all records will have "p1". Consider this an EAV model in hstore.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get that error - I get "functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE"

```
CREATE TABLE ht (ext hstore);
INSERT INTO ht VALUES ('p1=>"[10,18]"'), ('p1=>"[99,99]"');
CREATE INDEX ht_test_idx ON ht USING GIST ( ((ext->'p1'::text)::int4range) );
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

CREATE FUNCTION foo(hstore) RETURNS int4range LANGUAGE SQL AS $$ SELECT ($1->'p1')::int4range; $$ IMMUTABLE;
CREATE INDEX ht_test_idx ON ht USING GIST ( foo(ext) );
SET enable_seq_scan=false;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM ht WHERE foo(ext) = '[10,19)';
                              QUERY PLAN                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using ht_test_idx on ht  (cost=0.25..8.52 rows=1 width=32)
   Index Cond: (foo(ext) = '[10,19)'::int4range)
```

I'm guessing the cast isn't immutable because you can change the default format of the range from inclusive...exclusive "[...)" to something else. You presumably won't be doing that though.

Obviously you'll want your real function to deal with things like missing "p1" entries, badly formed range values etc.

Comment: I got the "IMMUTABLE" error when I tried to add a btree index. My queries will be on the key __ where value [_,_]. I'm not clear that what you wrote will function as an expression index on the keys.

Comment: Or do I need to create a function for each key? That doesn't seem to make sense. Basically some records will have 'p1", others won't. Consider this an EAV model in hstore.

Comment: OK - close this question (don't know how you do that) and post another one. Explain what you're really trying to achieve, because it's not clear from this. I can't quite see what purpose the data structure has or how you intend to use it.

Comment: Thanks. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856503/indexing-the-postgresql-hstore-type-with-an-int4range-value
I'll close this once you've seen the new question.